# R not reading header line from .txt file

Tags: r, header

I am just beginning to learn R and I can't figure out why the header line isn't being read in my data. Below is my very simple script with the error at the end saying one of my headers does not exist.

```
dat = read.table("D:/Wild_South/Linville_Gorge/HWA/Data/R_HWA.txt", header = T)

dat

    Treatment HWA Elevation

1           0 0.0      3072

2           0 0.0      3357

.
.
.
.

176         1 3.0      3898

177         1 3.0      3771

results = lm(HWA ~ Elevation + Treatment)
```

> Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'HWA' not found

Thoughts?

Comment: The problem is in your call to `lm` look at the help file for `lm` and you'll see that you need to specify the data set you want `lm` to use

Answer (score 4):

If I understand your issue correctly, you simply need to change the code to `results = lm(dat$HWA ~ dat$Elevation + dat$Treatment).` It is not the case that header line is not being read, but that the variables are not being identified correctly.

Comment: more standard (and fewer characters) to use `results = lm(HWA ~ Elevation + Treatment, data=dat)`.